# Unable to install tensor flow with pip?

Tags: tensorflow, pip

I just updated the latest MacOS and it wiped everything out.

I follow the steps from [this website](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

And I start reinstalling the tensorflow with pip3 and it's not installing anything.

I got this error from typing `pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow` .

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

FYI, my MacBook is 64-bit.
and

```
~ pip3 -V
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 20.2.4 from /Users/zack/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

~ python3 -V
Python 3.8.2
```

I don't know what happened does anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Hello can you run `pip3 -V` and `python3 -V` ?

Comment: @pavelbere I just updated.

Comment: What is the output of `python3 -c "from pip._internal.utils.compatibility_tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"`? It may indeed be due to the big sur update; I'm postponing the upgrade on mine macbook at least until 2.4.0 is out.

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location
and your version of python you should run

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl
```

This is the 3rd step, so check if you got installed correctly the packages from steps 1 and 2

Comment: I got a new error ```ERROR: tensorflow-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.```

Answer (score 0):

if pip is not up-to-date upgrade pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

then install tensorflow:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

for `python 3.8` you need to install `tensorflow 2.2` or later

system requirements of tensorflow:

Python 3.5–3.8
Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later.

pip 19.0 or later (requires manylinux2010 support)

Ubuntu 16.04 or later (64-bit)

macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (64-bit) (no GPU support)

Comment: I think the problem is because of the macOS Big Sur.